# How to get finger coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I can not find how I can get the coordinates of the mouse/finger on an iphone in Xcode.

I tried:

```
NSPoint mouseLoc;
mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
```

But this seems not to work for iphone?
The API does not recognise it.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Apple's doc: [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And in a `UIView` or `UIViewController`'s subclass you can add this method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touched = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touched.view];
    NSLog(@"x=%.2f y=%.2f", location.x, location.y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using cocoa classes.For iPhone there is cocoa.touch, the class you need it UIEvent.
The method allTouches returns all the touches events for the window.Once got a touch you can ask it's location in view.

**Example:**

```
void event : (UIEvent*) event
{
    NSSet* touches=[event allTouches];
    for(UITouch* touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint point=[touch locationInView: yourView];
        <Do what you need to do with the point>
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not completely understand the code I use is not working because it's from a different language? But I need to get the x and y coordinates of my finger/mouse on a iPhone.

Comment: Now I posted some example code.Your code wasn't working because was using another framework, cocoa is for max os x.The cocoa touch framework is for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer to recognize where finger touched on the screen. For this you have to add one UITapGestureRecognizer object/outlet on control where you want to handle touch such as in my example i am adding UITapGestureRecognizer on View.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(fingerTappedHere:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


- (void)fingerTappedHere:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

CGPoint touchedPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"x = %f, y = %f", touchedPoint.x, touchedPoint.y);
```

}

Hope it will help you. For further queries contact us at sales@agicent.com . We will try our best to resolve.