# How do I know the location where the finger touch starts and ends?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need the location where the finger touches to draw a line and the location of the line ending when I put away my Finger.

Which library should I use?
How can I perform that in xcode?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is to attach a UIPanGestureRecognizer to your view and interpret the messages you get from it.

You can also implement a custom subclass of UIView, set userInteractionEnabled = TRUE, and then implement the touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent:, and touchesEnded:withEvent: methods

You should be able to find lots of sample applications that show how to do this online. Try googling "UIPanGestureRecognizer draw line".

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377219/how-to-get-finger-coordinates).

Here is Apple's doc: [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And in a `UIView` or `UIViewController`'s subclass you can add this method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touched = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touched.view];
    NSLog(@"x=%.2f y=%.2f", location.x, location.y);
}
```

Comment: that only gets the start of a touch.

Comment: you would need to save the touches and match them up in touchesEnded. better to use Duncan's proposed way IMO